# Add Class and Delay Removing Class JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is keep an image showing while I add a class and then remove the class after the next image is showing. For example:

Image shown -> Add Class to show another image -> Next Image shown -> Remove class of first image.

I think I have my function mostly there, just needs a bit of tweaking. I have tried rearranging the code several different ways, but to no avail. Can someone see where I am going wrong. I have removed the setInterval function so there is working code.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="thumbnails left">
    <ul>
        <li class="" data-id="0"><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="1" class=""><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="2" class=""><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
         <li data-id="3" class="active"><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="full left">
     <ul style="height: 483px;">
        <li class="" data-id="0"><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="1" class=""><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="2" class=""><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
        <li data-id="3" class="active"><img alt="Precision Grinding" src="/assets/img/misc/precision_grinding.jpg"></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
function setActiveImage(){
  $('.thumbnails ul > li').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
        $('.thumbnails .active, .full .active').removeClass('active').stop();
        $('.thumbnails [data-id="'+id+'"], .full [data-id="'+id+'"]').addClass('active');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do, a cross-fade?

Comment: I guess. Right now the image goes away and the background of the page shows. I really want an image there at all times. But I want a slide effect. I have the slide effect down, but when I click on a thumbnail it removes a class and in turn slides the image out of the way with the background showing. It then slides the other image in. I always want an image there until another image has fully slid into the page. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you're using css animation? Can you set up a demo?

Comment: Yea give me a few minutes

Comment: http://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/BKWMWq

Sorry about that. Its a workable example. Not perfectly styled, but it works like I have it on my site now.

Comment: Try using adding delay attribute to addClass through jquery ui. https://jsfiddle.net/01k9m1qh/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you wanted... try this code ([demo](http://codepen.io/Mottie/pen/JXWxBJ))

CSS

```
.full ul > li.removing > img {
  z-index: 8888;
}

.full ul > li.active > img {
  transform: translateX(0%);
  /* delay removed */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.thumbnails ul > li').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
      var $this = $('.thumbnails [data-id="' + id + '"], .full [data-id="' + id + '"]');
      $this
        // check for end of transition event one time
        .one('transitionend', function() {
          $this
            // add "active" class to selected image, just-in-case
            // needed if user is a super-fast clicker, or transitions
            // is set to a bigger number (like 2s)
            .addClass('active')
            // find all sibling LI's of the selected image
            .siblings()
            // remove "active" class to start animation
            // remove "removing" class to reset z-index...
            // this might cause problems as z-index is reset too early
            .removeClass('active removing');
        })
        // start animation of selected image
        .addClass('active')
        // find sibling elements ("li") with an active class
        .siblings('.active')
        // add "removing" class to add a lower z-index to image to hide
        .addClass('removing');
    }
  });
});
```

There are times when the active panel slides into view after the last one slides out... I have no idea why it does that.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be what I was looking for, although, I don't understand everything you did here. Do you mind commenting the code?

Comment: Ok, sorry... a bunch of comments have been added. Now that I look at it, the "removing" class might not be needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you know the image transition/fade time, you could set up your own function to fade to the next image on a set interval.

Example:

```js
var cur_image = 0;
var last_image = 0;
var image_timer;

function fadeToNext() {
    var prev_image = cur_image;
    cur_image = ((cur_image+1) > last_image) ? 0: (cur_image+1);
    var next_image = ((cur_image+1) > last_image) ? 0: (cur_image+1);
  
    // Fade out previous image
    $('#images img').eq(prev_image).removeClass('show');
    
    // After 1s, switch on-top to current image and (in the background) fade-in next image
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#images img').eq(prev_image).removeClass('on-top');
      $('#images img').eq(cur_image).addClass('on-top');
      $('#images img').eq(next_image).addClass('show');
    }, 1000);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  last_image = ($('#images img').length - 1);
  
  $('#images img').first().addClass('show on-top').next().addClass('show');
  
  // Start fader (switches every 2s; 1s to fade-out previous and 1 to fade-in next)
  image_timer = setInterval(function(){
    fadeToNext();
  }, 2000);

  
});
```

```css
#images img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

#images img.show {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 2;
}

#images img.on-top {
  z-index:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="images">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%201&w=350&h=150">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%202&w=350&h=150">
  <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=Image%203&w=350&h=150">
</div>
```